# Node: How keep old objects and push new data into file Json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i want to fetch the old values from file Json if my script turns off from work and then insert the new values into the json file. i read the file and then converted the JSON file the code works safely, but i have a problem that it prints for me once

```js
const dataFile = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8')
let decodeJson = await JSON.parse(dataFile);
  decodeJson.table.push({name: 'test'})
```

this line is inside `forEach` loop so it is supposed to print 25 lines for each word test cuz after i want to write it in the same file data.json
this line for forEach

```js
getData.data.forEach(async details => {
  let currentPage = details.title;
  const dataFile = fs.readFileSync('data.json', 'utf8')
  if (dataFile === '') { // check if file json empty
    try {
      obj.table.push({
        name: details.title
      })
      let encodeJson = await JSON.stringify(obj);
      fs.writeFileSync("data.json", encodeJson)
      console.log('file is empty')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } else {
    //read data with JSON from file
    try {
      let decodeJson = await JSON.parse(dataFile);
      // i want here keep old values + push new values (details.title)
      decodeJson.table.push({
        name: 'test'
      })
      //fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(decodeJson))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
})
```

i tried some attempts but i failed and it still print me only one object...why?

```js
let data = []
data.push('test')
decodeJson.table.push(data)
```

this is the result i got in consolelog

```js
  table: [
    { name: 'Kimi ga Nozomu Eien' },
    { name: 'Kita e.: Diamond Dust Drops' },
    { name: 'Loveless' },
    { name: 'Blood+' },
    { name: 'Re: Cutey Honey' },
    { name: 'Solty Rei' },
    { name: 'Juuni Kokuki' },
    { name: 'Shaman King' },
    { name: 'X/1999' },
    { name: 'X' },
    { name: 'Mahou Sensei Negima!' },
    { name: 'Maria-sama ga Miteru' },
    { name: 'Boukyaku no Senritsu' },
    { name: 'Ima, Soko ni Iru Boku' },
    { name: 'Peace Maker Kurogane' },
    { name: 'Pita Ten' },
    { name: 'Power Stone' },
    { name: 'Mononoke Hime' },
    { name: 'RahXephon' },
    { name: 'Samurai 7' },
    { name: 'Scrapped Princess' },
    { name: 's.CRY.ed' },
    { name: 'Shingetsutan Tsukihime' },
    { name: 'Slam Dunk' },
    { name: 'Strange Dawn' },
    [ 'test' ]
  ]
}
```

also my goal that i want to do is if script stopped and start back work. it returns back the old object that was stored in the Json file + keeps adding a new object from the API i'm still a newbie and learning json so please treat me kindly

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is not asynchronous, you don't need to use `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `forEach` loops are synchronous

As already commented, neither `JSON.parse` nor `JSON.stringify` is asynchronous, so you don't need to use `await` for them.

Using `await` is causing the problem: `array.prototype.forEach` treats its argument as a  synchronous function and discards any value returned from it. Effectively this means any promises returned from an `async` function provided are discarded without waiting for the promise to be settled.

Also `async` function executing an `await` operator synchronously return a promise the first time an `await` operator is executed within them.

Hence if `data.json` is empty, the `await` in

```js
let encodeJson = await JSON.stringify(obj);
```

returns a promise before creating `data.json` content, which is sufficient for the `forEach` loop to continue. All remaining iterations will do the same and when resumed will overwrite the  `data.json` file created in the previous iteration. However, since each iteration updated an outer variable `obj`, the last version of `data.json` should be correct.

Similar conditions apply to an existing data file however: each loop iteration reads the existing file and returns a promise when

```js
await JSON.parse(dataFile);
```

is executed, allowing the next iteration to proceed and read the same input data and overwrite the file written by the previous iteration.

Major lessons are to not use `forEach` for asynchronous work that needs to complete within a single iteration, and not to use `await` in code that must execute synchronously.

In this particular case, leaving out the `await` operators, staying with synchronous writes, and removing  `async` before the loop function declaration should be sufficient to solve the issue. A better solution may be to read `data.json` once before starting the loop, and write it once after finishing the loop.